# DocuSign Signer Groups

Tags: docusignapi

Where should I go about creating and setting the signer groups as I am unable to see them in my DocuSign dashboard currently?
Can I create the signer groups in the API before defaulting them in the embed and send api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should note that **Signing Groups** functionality is not available on all DocuSign account plans so you should first verify your account plan.  Signing groups are available through sandbox accounts so you should be able to test at least.

To access Signing Groups click your profile icon in top right and go to **Admin -> Groups**.  If using Classic UI, go to **Preferences -> Account Admin -> Groups**. You can create and configure your signing groups from there.

Here are some additional resources regarding DocuSign Signing Groups:

1. https://support.docusign.com/en/videos/Creating-and-using-Signing-Groups
2. https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/cdse-user-guide/Content/advanced-sending/send-with-signing-groups.htm
3. https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-user-guide-sending-with-signing-groups