# Fill the document, save the changes and then send it to someone for signature

Tags: docusignapi

When I send the document to a recipient, that person has to fill in the values (not to sign) and then send the updated document to someone else for signature.

**Update From Comments:**

I need to send document to a first person, if the person is busy he need to send the document to second person that person has to fill and send it to the first person.Finally he review the document if there is any mistake he will correct it and sign. How to achieve this,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Editor Recipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#editors-recipient)

> Editors have the same management and access rights for the envelope as the sender. They can make changes to the envelope as if they were using the Advanced Correct feature. This recipient can add name and email information, add or change the routing order and set authentication options for the remaining recipients. Additionally, this recipient can edit signature/initial tabs and data fields for the remaining recipients. **The recipient must have a DocuSign account to be an editor**.

Here is a sample [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Envelope with Editor",
  "emailBlurb" :  "One editor and one signer",
  "status": "created",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "editors" : [
                        {
                            "name": "Jane Editor",
                            "email": "janeeditor@acme.com",
                            "routingOrder": "1",
                            "recipientId" : "1"
                        }
                    ],                      
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jane Signer",
                            "email": "janesigner@acme.com",
                            "roleName": "Signer1",
                            "routingOrder": "2",
                            "recipientId" : "2",

                        }
                    ]
                },
                "documents": [
                {
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "name": "Contract",
                    "fileExtension": "txt",
                    "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP"
                }
              ]
            }
        ]
    }       
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me with example  how to add email body(message) and email subject line from json to docusign template                 Note : Json string has to be passed as http request.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to give your recipient full edit capability to the envelope as suggested in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44524838/1219543),  then simply assign a text tab to the recipient at the first routing order.

In the below example, the recipient at routing order 1 will just have a text tab to fill. The recipient at routing order 2 can see the value filled by first recipient and sign the envelope.

Here is a sample [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Envelope with two signers",
  "emailBlurb" :  "Two signers one text tab one sign tab",
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jane Text",
                            "email": "janetext@acme.com",
                            "routingOrder": "1",
                            "recipientId" : "1",
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs" : [
                                    {
                                        "xPosition" : "100",
                                        "yPosition" : "100",
                                        "documentId" : "1",
                                        "pageNumber" : "1"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Jane Sign",
                            "email": "janesign@acme.com",
                            "routingOrder": "2",
                            "recipientId" : "2",
                            "tabs": {
                                "signHereTabs" : [
                                    {
                                        "xPosition" : "100",
                                        "yPosition" : "200",
                                        "documentId" : "1",
                                        "pageNumber" : "1"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }                                

                        }
                    ]
                },
                "documents": [
                {
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "name": "Contract",
                    "fileExtension": "txt",
                    "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP"
                }
              ]
            }
        ]
     }       
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But in our requirement we need to do this without routing order. We should not use routing order to do.Is there any other way to achieve this(Using configuration).Kindly let me know if you have any idea.

Thanks in advance, Vignesh.B

Comment: For your use case you will have to use routing order. There is no other way to achieve what you are asking.

Comment: See  here i need to send document to a first person.if the person is busy he need to send the document to second person that person has to fill and send it to the first person.Finally he review the document if there is any mistake he will correct it and sign.

How to achieve this,...

Comment: Added the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549607/1219543) to use signing groups. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DocuSign [signing groups](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/SigningGroups/SigningGroups/).

> Signing Groups allow you to create a group of people to which an envelope is sent. Any member of that group can open an envelope and sign the documents in the envelope with their own signature, even though a signature field was not directly assigned to them. When the Signing Group option is used, group members that open and sign the envelope are tracked in the envelope history and certificate.

```
{
  "status": "created",
  "emailSubject": "Test Email Subject",
  "emailBlurb": "Test Email Body",
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "signingGroupId": "12345",
        "recipientId": 1,
        "routingOrder": 1,
        "roleName": "Signer",
        "email": "signer_signingGroup_recipient@acme.com",
        "name": "Signer Name"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37933543/1219543) for more documentation.